# Qual a diferença em termos de navegação do UIViewController e SFSafariViewController?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, objective-c, webview

Gostaria de saber as vantagens e desvantagens dos controllers da webview [SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller) e [UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller), para as questões abaixo:
 - performance
 - compatibilidade
 - usabilidade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma situação recorrente no desenvolvimento mobile é mostrar o conteúdo de uma página web. Basicamente havia duas soluções para esse problema. A primeira era abrir o link no app do Safari, o que é bastante simples de implementar, porém gera uma experiência ruim ao usuário. A outra alternativa era desenvolver um 'mini-navegador', permitindo ao utilizador visualizar conteúdo web sem sair do app, mas tornando o desenvolvimento mais complexo, além da experiência ao usuário também não ser a ideal.

Então no iOS 9 foi introduzido o *SFSafariViewController*. Ele serve basicamente para abrir um navegador dentro do app e provê uma experiência de navegação superior, tal qual a do Safari. Além disso requer quase nenhum esforço de desenvolvimento. 
No entanto, o uso do *SFSafariViewController* é bastante restrito. Esse componente é uma subclasse de UIViewController, que recebe uma URL na inicialização.
Um exemplo de aplicação é abrir um link web quando o usuário clica sobre ele ou para abrir um determinado website.

*UIViewController* pode ser visto como uma entidade que controla o layout, o conteúdo e o tratamento de eventos da interface ao usuário. Normalmente para cada tela do App existe um *UIViewController*. Em geral, os componentes da interface são definidos em um arquivo separado (.xib, .storyboard) e no ViewController modificamos o conteúdo da interface, traram-se eventos como clicks e de mudança de estado (ex: *viewDidLoad*, *viewDidDisappear*), dentre muitas outras atribuições.

Como os propósitos de *UIViewController* e *SFSafariViewController* são distintos, é difícil fazer a comparação. *SFSafariViewController* não oferece muita customização e se parece com um browser. É indicado quando o app simplesmente precisa abrir uma página web. Caso na sua aplicação seja necessário mais flexibilidade sobre como o conteúdo web é mostrado ou para outras aplicações mais específicas, a solução é utilizar *WKWebView*. Esse componente é adicionado na hierarquia de views do ViewController e então é necessário implementar o código para carregar a URL desejada e tratar eventos.